# Apache RewriteRule Issues - Different behaviour local compared to server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having some very weird issues with a simple RewriteRule that is working as it should locally but when deployed to the server I'm getting 500 errors with the text:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

The following is the code that I am using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(foo|bar|baz)/?
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/410/index.php$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /410/index.php? [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I want is anything other than `/foo`, `/bar`, or `/baz` to show the page located at /410/index.php

Yes, mod_rewrite.c is installed/enabled on the server.

Comment: Are you doing any rewrites in a `.htaccess` file somewhere? That's likely where the loop is coming into play.

Comment: Hi AbsoluteƵERØ; yes these rules are in a .htaccess file.  No other .htaccess file is present in the sub-directories (especially under the `410` directory).  I wouldn't think it would make a difference...  The apache config is setup to allow override, so it should work.

Comment: Are there any rewrites in the `httpd.conf` or an included file? Unless the rewrite rules are set to inherit a `.htaccess` file in the 401 folder would override one in the `root`. Additionally is anything else doing a redirect, like a PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for an `.htaccess` file try removing the slash preceding the "410" in the rewrite rule. Also if you check to see if it's a real file that should stop the endless redirects back to the index page.

I'm going to take a guess and say there is the slight chance (and I couldn't find documentation on this) that the request string you're rewriting with the `?` to flush the existing query string might not being matched.

```
RewriteEngine On
#check if it's a not a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Check if the request doesn't start with foo, bar, or baz
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(foo|bar|baz)
#Check if uri doesn't only contain the /410/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/410/index.php\??$
#rewrite the file
RewriteRule ^.*$ 410/index.php? [L]
```